# Optimal Strategy in unfair dice

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have an unfair 12 sided die. It rolls a 12 40% of the time and equally likely to roll any other face. You and I are playing a game where both of us try to guess the number on the die before rolling and whoever gets closer to that number wins. What’s your strategy?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Your strategy will depend on your game. For example, the game "Who rolls 12 first" and the game "Who rolls 12 last" will have 2 different strategies.

Comment: @F.Conrad sorry, I've edited the qn now to include "the game"

Comment: If I choose, say, $9$ then it only makes sense for you to pick $8$ or $10$. You can compute the odds of each of these cases to find the best one. Then you can try to explore other first picks (say $10$) and repeat.

Comment: @Winther Unclear whether your intepretation is intended by the problem composer.  Unknown whether Person-1's guess is (for example) by secret ballot or is announced to Person-2, before Person-2 makes their guess.

Comment: Thanks that makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Under the assumption that guesses are by secret ballot, then, the problem becomes **much more complicated**.  First, you would have to explore which guess lowers your expected **guess-error**.  Then, assuming that both players are both perfectly rational/logical and both players assume that the other player is also perfectly rational/logical, you then have to determine the optimal counter-strategy to the optimal guess that minimizes **guess-error**.  ...see next comment

Comment: Then, in true **Rock-Paper-Scissors** fashion, you have to select an array of guesses, with each guess made with a certain frequency.  The idea would be to define **perfect play** so that no matter what strategy your opponent adopts, your win/loss expectation under secret ballot is **never negative**.

Comment: Must the players' guesses be one of the numbers $1$ to $12$, or can they choose non-integers such as $6.5$, which could plausibly be a better choice if it were allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are ambiguities in your description of this game, some of which have been raised in the comments and still remain to be clarified.  Here is one plausible interpretation for which the game will have a well-defined pair of optimal strategies.

I assume both players first choose one of the integers between $1$ and $12$ inclusive.  The die is then rolled and if either player's chosen number is closer to the number rolled than that of his or her opponent, then that player is paid one unit of money by the other.  If both numbers are equidistant from the number rolled, then neither player pays anything to the other.  Each player's aim is to maximise his or her expected winnings.  Thus specified, the game becomes a [matrix game](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Matrix_game)—that is, a zero-sum game with a finite number of pure strategies for both players.

If the players choose their numbers by secret ballot, then each has $12$ pure strategies, each of which specifies a different one of the numbers from $1$ to $12$ as the one to be chosen.  If the first player has to choose his or her number first and then reveal it to the other, then the latter can make his or her chosen number depend on what the first player chooses. The second player's pure strategies are then the functions $\ f:\{1,2,\dots,12\}$$\,\rightarrow\{1,2,\dots,12\}\ $, of which there are $12^{12}$.  As it happens, the unique optimal strategy for the first player is to choose the number $10$, regardless of whether this has to be revealed to the second player or not.  If the first player does this, then the other can do no better than to choose $10$ also, and will do *worse* if he or she *doesn't* choose $10$.

If both players choose the same number, then both of them receive $0$. If the first player chooses  $\ i<12\ $, the second player chooses $\ j>i\ $, and the number rolled is $\ r\ $, then the first  wins $1$ unit from the second whenever $\ r<\frac{i+j}{2}\ $, and the second wins $1$ unit from the first whenever $\ r>\frac{i+j}{2}\ $.  If $\ r=\frac{i+j}{2}\ $, which obviously can only occur when $\ i+j\ $ is even, then neither player loses or wins anything.  The probability that $\ r<\frac{i+j}{2}\ $ is $\ \frac{3}{55}\left(\left\lceil\frac{i+j}{2}\right\rceil-1\right)\ $ and the probability that $\ r>\frac{i+j}{2}\ $ is $\ \frac{2}{5}+\frac{3}{55}\left(11-\left\lfloor\frac{i+j}{2}\right\rfloor\right)=1-\frac{3}{55}\left\lfloor\frac{i+j}{2}\right\rfloor\ $.  The first player's expected winnings are therefore
$$
\frac{3}{55}\left(\left\lceil\frac{i+j}{2}\right\rceil-1\right)-1+\frac{3}{55}\left\lfloor\frac{i+j}{2}\right\rfloor=\frac{3(i+j)-58}{55}\ ,
$$
and the second's are just the negative of that.  The players' payoffs are tabulated in the following matrix, where the entry in row $\ i\ $ and column $\ j\ $ of the matrix is a player's expected  winnings when he or she chooses $\ i\ $ and his or her opponent chooses $\ j\ $.
$$
\pmatrix{0&\frac{-49}{55}&\frac{-46}{55}&\frac{-43}{55}&\frac{-8}{11}&\frac{-37}{55}&\frac{-34}{55}&\frac{-31}{55}&\frac{-28}{55}&\frac{-5}{11}&\frac{-2}{5}&\frac{-19}{55}\\
\frac{49}{55}&0&\frac{-43}{55}&\frac{-8}{11}&\frac{-37}{55}&\frac{-34}{55}&\frac{-31}{55}&\frac{-28}{55}&\frac{-5}{11}&\frac{-2}{5}&\frac{-19}{55}&\frac{-16}{55}\\
\frac{46}{55}&\frac{43}{55}&0&\frac{-37}{55}&\frac{-34}{55}&\frac{-31}{55}&\frac{-28}{55}&\frac{-5}{11}&\frac{-2}{5}&\frac{-19}{55}&\frac{-16}{55}&\frac{-13}{55}\\
\frac{43}{55}&\frac{8}{11}&\frac{37}{55}&0&\frac{-31}{55}&\frac{-28}{55}&\frac{-5}{11}&\frac{-2}{5}&\frac{-19}{55}&\frac{-16}{55}&\frac{-13}{55}&\frac{-2}{11}\\
\frac{8}{11}&\frac{37}{55}&\frac{34}{55}&\frac{31}{55}&0&\frac{-5}{11}&\frac{-2}{5}&\frac{-19}{55}&\frac{-16}{55}&\frac{-13}{55}&\frac{-2}{11}&\frac{-7}{55}\\
\frac{37}{55}&\frac{34}{55}&\frac{31}{55}&\frac{28}{55}&\frac{5}{11}&0&\frac{-19}{55}&\frac{-16}{55}&\frac{-13}{55}&\frac{-2}{11}&\frac{-7}{55}&\frac{-4}{55}\\
\frac{34}{55}&\frac{31}{55}&\frac{28}{55}&\frac{5}{11}&\frac{2}{5}&\frac{19}{55}&0&\frac{-13}{55}&\frac{-2}{11}&\frac{-7}{55}&\frac{-4}{55}&\frac{-1}{55}\\
\frac{31}{55}&\frac{28}{55}&\frac{5}{11}&\frac{2}{5}&\frac{19}{55}&\frac{16}{55}&\frac{13}{55}&0&\frac{-7}{55}&\frac{-4}{55}&\frac{-1}{55}&\frac{2}{55}\\
\frac{28}{55}&\frac{5}{11}&\frac{2}{5}&\frac{19}{55}&\frac{16}{55}&\frac{13}{55}&\frac{2}{11}&\frac{7}{55}&0&\frac{-1}{55}&\frac{2}{55}&\frac{1}{11}\\
\frac{5}{11}&\frac{2}{5}&\frac{19}{55}&\frac{16}{55}&\frac{13}{55}&\frac{2}{11}&\frac{7}{55}&\frac{4}{55}&\frac{1}{55}&0&\frac{1}{11}&\frac{8}{55}\\
\frac{2}{5}&\frac{19}{55}&\frac{16}{55}&\frac{13}{55}&\frac{2}{11}&\frac{7}{55}&\frac{4}{55}&\frac{1}{55}&\frac{-2}{55}&\frac{-1}{11}&0&\frac{1}{5}\\
\frac{19}{55}&\frac{16}{55}&\frac{13}{55}&\frac{2}{11}&\frac{7}{55}&\frac{4}{55}&\frac{1}{55}&\frac{-2}{55}&\frac{-1}{11}&\frac{-8}{55}&\frac{-1}{5}&0}
$$
Notice that the entries in row $\ 10\ $ of this payoff matrix are all positive except for the one in column $10$, which is zero, and the entries in column $\ 10\ $ are all negative, except for that in row $10$, which is zero. Thus, the pair of choices $\ (10,10)\ $ is a [saddle point](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Saddle_point_in_game_theory).  By choosing the number $10$, either player ensures that his or her expected winnings are non-negative, and will be strictly positive unless  the other player also chooses $10$.  The player's expected winnings will also be *strictly negative* if he or she does *not* choose $10$ and the other player does.

When the second player is told the first player's choice before he or she has to make one, that player's optimal choice and expected winnings are given in the following table:
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\text{player }1\text{'s}\\
\text{choice}&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12\\
\hline
\text{optimal reply}&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&10&10&11\\
\hline
\text{expected}\\
\text{winnings}&\frac{49}{55}&\frac{43}{55}&\frac{37}{55}&\frac{31}{55}&\frac{5}{11}&\frac{19}{55}&\frac{13}{55}&\frac{7}{55}&\frac{1}{55}&0&\frac{1}{11}&\frac{1}{5}\\
\hline
\end{array}
In all cases, the second player's optimal choice is unique.

Answer (score 2):

You state the objective of the game as:

> whoever gets closer to that number wins

Since the roll of the die is assumed to be independent for each roll, and cannot be modified by any of the 2 players, i.e., not an adversarial game, then it would appear to me that there is a fixed optimal strategy independent of the other player's. If both players use this strategy, then both will win 50% of the time each, on average.

There are 2 very similar strategies, both are fixed-in-advance, but they differ in that the first is deterministic and the second is randomized. The 2nd (randomized) strategy is on average always **better** than the 1st (deterministic) one. This corresponds to the observation by @RossMillikan in the comment.

**Strategy 1 is deterministic:**

It would appear to me the best strategy is to always choose the number $k$ which minimizes the following expected absolute difference loss:
$$\hat{k} = arg min_k{E_i[|i - k|]} = arg min_k{ \Sigma_{i=1..N}|i - k| \cdot p_i}$$
where
$$N = 12, \text{  } p_{12} = 0.4, \text{  } p_{i | i < 12} = \frac{1 - p}{N - 1} = 0.0545454...$$

The values of the expected loss for each $k$, rounded to 4 decimal digits, are:

```
1:  7.4
2:  6.5091
3:  5.7273
4:  5.0545
5:  4.4909
6:  4.0364
7:  3.6909
8:  3.4545
9:  3.3273
10:  3.3091
11:  3.4
12:  3.6
```

The choice $\hat{k} = 10$ minimizes this loss. **So always choose the value 10**.

Sanity-checks:

- plugging-in $p_{12} = 1/N$ (fair die) will give the intuitive optimal choice $\hat{k} = 6 \text{ or } 7$, i.e., the middle of the range
- plugging-in $p_{12} = 1.0$ (the die will always roll 12) will give the intuitive optimal choice $\hat{k} = 12$

**Strategy 2 is randomized:**

Although it is still fixed-in-advance, in the sense of being independent of the actions or strategy of the other player, and independent of the unknown roll of the die.

This 2nd (randomized) strategy is on average always **better** than the 1st (deterministic) one. This corresponds to the observation by @RossMillikan in the comment.

To motivate this strategy, observe the loss function described in the 1st strategy, but where we are **not** constraining the $k$ values to be integers, i.e., continuous $k$ values. See the following zoomed-in image:
[Sorry, cannot upload the image due to some server error... perhaps I do not have enough reputation points?]

The loss where we are **not** constraining the $k$ values to be integers is a parabola, which passes through all the integer $k$ points, but whose minimum value is approximately at $\hat{k} \approxeq 9.665$

Of course, the final choice for any strategy must eventually be an integer, so a randomized choice is made in the following way:

- Choose the value $k_1 = 10$ with probability $q = 9.665 - 9 = 0.665$
- Choose the value $k_2 = 9$ with probability $1 - q = 0.335$

Of course as a player, I must proclaim either $k_1 = 10$ or $k_2 = 9$ before the die roll... (determined by a different independent binary random number generator with probability $q = 0.665$)  As stated before, this choice is completely independent of the choice of the 2nd player.

Comment: If you choose $10$ and I choose $9$, I will win $\frac 9{11}\cdot 60\% \approx 49\%$ of the time, so I should choose $10$ as this says.  If the $12$ were a little less probable $9$ vs. $10$ would be winning.

Comment: @RossMillikan Yes, your observation is correct. I showed a deterministic strategy, where I always choose the same $k$. There is an even better "fixed" but randomized strategy. I will update the post with it.